# How to add metadata to tm Corpus object with tm_map

Tags: r, apply, tm

I have been reading different questions/answers (especially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960863/r-tm-textmining-package-doc-level-metadata-generation-is-slow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090001/how-to-set-author-for-each-doc-in-a-corpus-by-parsing-doc-id)) without managing to apply any to my situation.

I have a 11,390 rows matrix with attributes id, author, text, such as:

```
library(tm)

m <- cbind(c("01","02","03","04","05","06"),
           c("Author1","Author2","Author2","Author3","Author3","Auhtor4"),
           c("Text1","Text2","Text3","Text4","Text5","Text6"))
```

I want to create a `tm` corpus out of it. I can quickly create my corpus with

```
tm_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(m[,3]))
```

which terminates execution for my 11,390 rows matrix in

```
   user  system elapsed 
  2.383   0.175   2.557
```

But then when I try to add metadata to the corpus with

```
meta(tm_corpus, type="local", tag="Author") <- m[,2]
```

the execution time is over the 15 minutes and counting (I then stopped execution).

According to the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960863/r-tm-textmining-package-doc-level-metadata-generation-is-slow) chances are to decreasing significantly the time in processing the corpus with `tm_map`; something like

```
tm_corpus <- tm_map(tm_corpus, addMeta, m[,2])
```

Still I am not sure how to do this. Probably it is going to be something like

```
addMeta <- function(text, vector) {
  meta(text, tag="Author") = vector[??]
  text
}
```

For one thing how to pass to `tm_map` a vector of values to be assign to each text of the corpus? Should I call the function from within a loop? Should I enclose the `tm_map` function within `vapply`?

Comment: for me the meta call works. the only difference is that i used "corpus" as type: meta(tm_corpus, type="corpus", tag="Author") <- m[,2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `tm_map` is faster and it is the way to go. You should use it here with a global counter.

```
auths <- paste0('Author',seq(11390))
i <- 0
tm_corpus = tm_map(tm_corpus, function(x) {
   i <<- i +1
   meta(x, "Author") <- m[i,2]
   x
})
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you already tried the excellent [readTabular](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/extensions.pdf)?

```
## your sample data
matrix <- cbind(c("01","02","03","04","05","06"),
       c("Author1","Author2","Author2","Author3","Author3","Auhtor4"),
       c("Text1","Text2","Text3","Text4","Text5","Text6"))

## simple transformations
matrix <- as.data.frame(matrix)
names(matrix) <- c("id", "author", "content")
```

Now your ex-matrix now data.frame can be read easily in as a corpus using readTabular.  ReadTabular wants you to define a Reader which itselfs takes a mapping.  In your mapping "content" points to the text data and the other names - well - to meta.

```
## define myReader, which will be used in creation of Corpus
myReader <- readTabular(mapping=list(id="id", author="author", content="content"))
```

Now the creation of the Corpus is same as always, apart from small changes:

```
## create the corpus
tm_corpus <- DataframeSource(matrix)
tm_corpus <- Corpus(tm_corpus,
    readerControl = list(reader=myReader))
```

Now have a look at the content and meta data of the first items:

```
lapply(tm_corpus, as.character)
lapply(tm_corpus, meta)
## output just as expected.
```

This should be fast, as it is part of the package and **extremely adaptable**.  In my own project I am using this on a data.table with some 20 variables - it works like a charm.

However I cannot provide benchmarking with the answer you have already approved as suitable.  I simply guess it is faster and more efficient.

Comment: For `lapply(tm_corpus, as.character)`, what is this showing? I see everything is in `lapply(tm_corpus, meta)` now

Comment: The first command shows the text (and only the text), the second one the „meta“ information, at least in my setup. Did you get different results?

Comment: This does not seem to work when you only have one column in the dataframe.  Aggravating.

Comment: You need an index in any case, so at least two columns, yeah. But an index is easy to create, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Since readTabular from tm package has been deprecated, now the solution might be like this:

```
matrix <- cbind(c("Author1","Author2","Author2","Author3","Author3","Auhtor4"),
                c("Text1","Text2","Text3","Text4","Text5","Text6"))
matrix <- as.data.frame(matrix)
names(matrix) <- c("doc_id", "text")
tm_corpus <- DataframeSource(matrix)
tm_corpus <- Corpus(tm_corpus)
inspect(tm_corpus)
meta(tm_corpus)
```